# How to call method of wrapped object by unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm able to compile the following code where I pass a "callback" to an object (Table). What I'm trying to do now is inside Table, call the **handle** method defined in **EventListener**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Table {

  public:
    struct Listener{ 
      virtual void handle(int i) = 0;
    };

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Listener>> listeners_;

    void add_listener(std::unique_ptr<Listener> l){
      listeners_.push_back(std::move(l));
    }

};


struct EventListener: public Table::Listener {
  void handle(int e){  
    std::cout << "Something happened! " << e << " \n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Table table;
  std::unique_ptr<EventListener> el;
  table.add_listener(std::move(el));

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT ****

This is what Im trying inside Table. It results in a segmentation fault:

```
for (auto t =0; t < (int)listeners_.size(); ++t) {
   listeners_[t]->handle(event); 
}
```

Comment: So what's preventing you from iterating the vector and invoking the `handle` function?

Comment: and? what is the problem?

Comment: This doesn´t work: listeners_[t]->handle(event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you never created an object for it to be called on, just a pointer. The pointer inside the vector will be `nullptr` and therefore calling the function on it will crash. `unique_ptr` has absolutely nothing to do with this problem.

Half the problem is that `Table` cannot handle `nullptr` but doesn't check for it, and the other half the problem is that `Table` cannot handle `nullptr` but `main` passes one in anyway.

The iteration code is not the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by Puppy the line

```
std::unique_ptr<EventListener> el;
```

creates an empty `std::unique_ptr`. This causes the code for nivoking the 
listeners to later dereference a `nullptr`.

A simple fix for your example is to create a listener and use that
when creating the `unique_ptr`:

```
struct EventListener: public Table::Listener {
  void handle(int e){  
    std::cout << "Something happened! " << e << " \n";
  }
};

// in main()
std::unique_ptr<NoOpListener> el{ new NoOpListener };
table.add_listener(std::move(el));
```

As mentioned in the comments your code should ensure that nullptr
isn't allowed. One way of doing this would be to add a check for 
nullptr in `add_listener` and throw an exception or silently ignore
them. The first option is the better solution of the two as it
signals the caller that something is wrong.

But I don't see why you would store listeners in `std::unique_ptr`s. 
The use for `std::unique_ptr` is for ownership. I do not see why the
observed instance should own the listeners. There is another alternative 
that I think is better; use `std::function<>()` and pass it by value.
This disallows the use of `nullptr` and has the added bonus of accepting 
not only function objects, but also normal functions and lambdas as shown
in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class Table {
  public:
    std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> listeners_;

    void add_listener(std::function<void(int)> l) {
      listeners_.push_back(l);
    }

    void invoke_listeners(int event)
    {
      for(auto l : listeners_) {
        l(event);
      }
    }
};


struct NoOpListener  {
  void operator() (int i) {
    std::cout << "NoOpListener::operator()(" << i << ")" << std::endl;
  }
};

void cb(int i) {
  std::cout << "cb(" << i << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Table table;
  table.add_listener(NoOpListener{});
  table.add_listener(cb);
  table.add_listener([](int i) { std::cout << "[lambda](" << i << ")" << std::endl; });
  table.invoke_listeners(10);
  return 0;
}
```

NOTE: As you can see I also used the C++11 ranged-for construct for iterating
over the listeners.